# Using knockoutjs click binding, how do I pass a value from one viewmodel to another?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have been searching everywhere and have not seen this particular scenario explained. I would appreciate any help anyone can provide! I am using knockoutjs and jQuery. I am trying to use a click binding inside a foreach binding to pass a data value to another viewmodel. I am retrieving the data object from the click event, but I do not understand how to read an actual value in that data object so I can pass it to the second viewmodel.

Here is my html from the 1st viewmodel:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in" data-bind="foreach: { data: model.savingsAccounts, afterRender: changeOption }">
  <div class="accordion-inner" data-bind="css: getRow(), click: $parent.goToDetails">
      <span class="tableArrow">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="tableColumnLeft">Savings<br><span data-bind="text: $data.accountNum" /></span>
      <span class="tableColumnCenter">$<span data-bind="text: $data.currentBalance" /></span><span class="tableColumnRight">></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to pass the "$data.accountNum" value of "12345" to the second viewmodel when goToDetails evaluates.

Here's what I have in goToDetails, which is defined in my return module:

```
goToDetails: function (data, event) {
            var thisItem = koMapping.fromJSON(data.data);
            alert(thisItem.accountNum);
            details.currentAccountID = thisItem.accountNum;
            shell.navigate('details', 'next');
        },
```

Here is the data in my object:

```
+ this
+ arguments
- data
     accountNum     "12345"
     accountType    "Savings"
     currentBalance "10.22"
+ event
```

The alert displays "undefined" for the value of thisItem.accountNum. How do I get the actual value for accountNum? Also, do you all have a better suggestion for passing a value to a 2nd viewmodel than setting it before I navigate there? I cannot use the query string unfortunately. Also, we do not have a session in place.

Thank you very much for your time!

Adding our entire viewmodel.js code as requested:

```
define(['knockout', 'knockout-mapping', 'jquery', 'viewmodels/shell', 'viewmodels/details'], function (ko, koMapping, $, shell, details) {

    var self = this;
    var savingsAccounts = ko.observableArray();

    self.activeOption = 'A';

    self.changeOption = function() {
        if (self.activeOption == 'A') {
            self.activeOption = 'B';
        } else {
            self.activeOption = 'A';
        }
    };

    self.getRow = function() {
        if (self.activeOption == 'A') {
            return 'balancesRowB';
        } else {
            return 'balancesRowA';
        }
    };

    function buildSavingsAccounts() {
        savingsAccounts([ 
        { accountNum: '12345', accountType: 'Savings', currentBalance: '10.22' }
    ]);

    }


    // module instance
    return {
        model: {
            savingsAccounts: savingsAccounts
        },
        activate: function (activationData) {
            buildSavingsAccounts();         
        },
        goToDetails: function (data, event) {
            var thisItem = koMapping.fromJSON(data.data);
            alert(thisItem.accountNum);
            details.currentAccountID = thisItem.accountNum;
            shell.navigate('details', 'next');
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: could you paste you binding javsacript code?

Comment: Here is our complete viewmodel.js. Please let me know if you would like to see anything else.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using the ko.mapping plugin. Also, you probably shouldn't use 'data.data'. If you just do console.log(data.accountNum); on the first line in goToDetails it should log the accountNum value just fine.

Comment: The quick and dirty is to put a function in the page your are using and have that be the go between function

Comment: Thank you, I updated my code to reference data.accountNum and I am retrieving the value. I tried that previously, but must have had something wrong with my syntax. Thanks for hanging with me... I'm somewhat new to knockoutjs. I'm now working on trying to pass the value to the 2nd viewmodel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you have the element that both viewModels are tied to you can use the:

```
ko.contextFor(element);
```

This will give you access to the view model of the other element. In this case 'element' is the actual element not the jQuery selector.